# Send string from flutter to iOS

Tags: ios, swift, dart, flutter

[image: Add new contact screen]

I'm trying to add a new contact to the `iOS` platform. I have the data (name, phone number, etc.) on the Flutter side in `Dart` and I want to send it to `iOS` side, open the screen for adding contacts (as in WhatsApp when you want to add new contact directly from the app) and prepopulate some fields based on the data I send from Flutter.

Now, as I understand, I have to open that screen on the `iOS` side. What I want to do is send a single argument from `Dart`, a string like `Name | LastName | phoneNumber`. Then I'd parse it in `Swift` and run a function that will open the screen for adding new contact and pass the fields as arguments to the function to populate selected fields.

Other option would be to create a `JSON` object on the `Dart` side and send it to `iOS` side, parse it and call the function for adding new contact with named arguments. The rest is the same.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You probably want to use the [contacts_service](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_service) plugin.

Comment: This [link](https://blog.testfairy.com/flutter-and-native-communication/) will teach you how to parse the message passed from the `Dart` to `Swift`. But as there is already a plugin to manage contacts so you can use that.

Comment: I'v looked into that before but I've seen this issue and it seems it's not resolved: https://github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_contacts/issues/31

Comment: But this tutorial you linked uses `MethodChannel` instead of `MessageChannel`